# Pass additional attribute to django-filter

Tags: python, django, django-filter, drf-queryset

I'm using django-filter together with DRF. I have a `favourite`-model, which is linked to several other models through a GenericRelation.
To filter for entries which have a favourite-flag, I've created a custom `FavouriteFilter`, which I add to the respective model. I would like to query for the `content_type_id` of the respective model in order to limit the results from `Favourite`. However, I don't know how I can pass down the `model` to the filter-method in the `FavouriteFilter`.

Here's a code snippet to illustrate the issue:

```python
class ProjectFilter(BaseFilter):

    favourite_only = FavouriteFilter()


class FavouriteFilter(django_filters.BooleanFilter):
    """
    A custom filter which returns a users favourites of an element
    """

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # gettext_lazy breaks the OpenAPI generation => use gettext instead
        kwargs['label'] = gettext("My favourites")
        super(FavouriteFilter, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def filter(self, qs, value):
        if value == True:
            user = get_current_user()
            content_type = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(<model>)
            return qs.filter(pk__in=Favourite.objects
                             .filter(owner_id=user)
                             .filter(content_type_id=content_type)
                             .values_list('object_id', flat=True)
                             )
        else:
            return qs
```

In this example, the `<model>`-attribute is missing. How can I pass down this information from `Project` to the filter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keyword arguments can be passed down to the filter, but they need to be removed from the kwarg-dict before the super()-method is called. Otherwise they get passed on to the superclass, the superclass's `__init__()`-method doesn't know the keyword and a `TypeError` is thrown:

```
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'model'
```

In the example above, the superclass is `django_filters.BooleanFilter` respectively `django_filters.Filter`.

Using the [`dict.pop()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.pop)-method, the keyword is removed from the kwargs-dictionary and at the same time we can save it for further use. Since `content_type` never changes after initialization, it can already be set in `__init__()`.

Here's a working example of the code above, where `Project` is the django-model I want to pass down to the filter:

```python
class ProjectFilter(BaseFilter):

    favourite_only = FavouriteFilter(model=Project)


class FavouriteFilter(django_filters.BooleanFilter):
    """
    A custom filter which returns a users favourites of an element
    """

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # gettext_lazy breaks the OpenAPI generation => use gettext instead
        kwargs['label'] = gettext("My favourites")
        model = kwargs.pop('model')
        self.content_type = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(model)
        super(FavouriteFilter, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def filter(self, qs, value):
        if value == True:
            user = get_current_user()
            return qs.filter(pk__in=Favourite.objects
                             .filter(owner_id=user)
                             .filter(content_type_id=self.content_type)
                             .values_list('object_id', flat=True)
                             )
        else:
            return qs
```

For my specific use-case, where I'm looking for the model that is using the filter, the model is available through the queryset as `qs.model`. The code-snippet looks like this:

```python
class ProjectFilter(BaseFilter):

    favourite_only = FavouriteFilter()


class FavouriteFilter(django_filters.BooleanFilter):
    """
    A custom filter which returns a users favourites of an element
    """

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # gettext_lazy breaks the OpenAPI generation => use gettext instead
        kwargs['label'] = gettext("My favourites")
        super(FavouriteFilter, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def filter(self, qs, value):
        if value == True:
            user = get_current_user()
            content_type = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(qs.model)
            return qs.filter(pk__in=Favourite.objects
                             .filter(owner_id=user)
                             .filter(content_type_id=content_type)
                             .values_list('object_id', flat=True)
                             )
        else:
            return qs
```